# Returning from exile at end step

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I've been playing magic on and off for a long time. The most recent time, however I've been taking a closer look at rules and action orders.

The main thing that I've been doing now is cloudshifting allies in and out of play. I need explanation on returning to exile at the end step. Blessed vs. Cused spotlighted a card that exiles all creatures I want that I control and sends them back at the end step. I didn't know it was any different from returning during the rest of the turn, until a buddy said something about it being different. He basically said that instead of returning one by one and triggering separately each time, they all hit at once and only trigger once.

Is this true? If it is can someone explain the ruling and process?

Comment: They entering the battlefield simultaneously is usually actually a good thing because they can see each other entering. If you have for example four Ondu Cleric you will get 4 x 4 x 4 life. If they didn't enter simultaneously it would only be 4 x 4 + 3 x 4 + 2 x 4 + 4

Comment: It sounds like this question is primarily about if returning during the end step is different than returning any other time. That is not answered by the answer here or by the suggested duplicate.

Comment: @GendoIkari - While the Question is built on a confusion between the difference in what would happen for multiple objects entering the battlefield during the end step compared to the rest of the turn, the accepted answer of the marked duplicate highlights "whenever multiple objects enter the battlefield at the same time, their enters the battlefield triggers will all see all of them as on the battlefield," which is phase agnostic.

Comment: @Ivo Beckers, I was under the assumption it would be 4 life 4x2 life 4x3 life 4x4 life. But looking at it again I can see why now knowing that the etb checks after they all clear and not one by one.

Comment: The next thing would be with Zada, Hedron Grinder and cloudshift, they wouldn't technically enter at the same time right? It copies the spell I prioritize them on the stack then they resolve one by one blinking in each creature one at a time, right?

Comment: @Theexiledmage That is a different case. Each Copy of Cloudshift resolves separately, blinking one creature at a time. You order the copies however you chose.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, they all enter the battlefield at once, but each trigger will be triggered.
When they enter simultaneously, they 'see' each other. If you have an Ally who gives lifelink, one who gives +1/+0 and one who gives +1/+1, the net result of them entering the battlefield at the same time would be +6/+3 and three instances of lifelink (which doesn't make any difference to just one instance, since it's not additive) for your three allies